# Is there a method to have rsync write only errors to a log file?

Tags: rsync

I have a situation where I need to (almost)completely copy my Ubuntu HD to an external HD. The biggest problem I and encountering is that there are an extremely large number of files that won't copy for various reasons.

If I could get rsync to write only the errors it encounters to a log file, then I could use that file to create bash file to get me further along. By errors I mean any situation where a file won't copy, regardless of reason.

When I use the log option the log file is too large as it contains info on every file. So large I am unable to even open it.

```
rsync  /source/ /dest/ --log-file=error.log
```

When I tried the quiet option outputing the screen to a file, the log file I get is empty.

```
rsync -q /source/ /dest/ > error.log
```

Is there anyway to get rsync to write to a file, only the errors it has encountered?

Comment: just search log file with "grep 'rsync:' file" to find errors

Comment: @petep The log file is way too large. My editor will not open it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsync` writes error in `stderr` therefore `error.log` is empty in the following case

```
rsync -q /source/ /dest/ > error.log
```

Instead of the above run the following command

```
rsync -q <options> /source/ /dest/ 2> error.log
```

Now all the errors will be saved on `error.log`.

Comment: Can anybody tell why this answer was downvoted? I would like to know if there's something wrong with this answer as it helps me get a deeper knowledge about how things work.

Comment: This answer worked for me, the second command did everything I needed.

Comment: I should add that I didn't even try the first option. Process too lengthy to try both.